# What is the best/good way of exchanging ETH with your own token?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development

I'm currently researching ways of exchanging ETH with my own token.

I saw [this](https://stermi.medium.com/how-to-create-an-erc20-token-and-a-solidity-vendor-contract-to-sell-buy-your-own-token-8882808dd905) article about vendor contracts that you could use to exchange your own token.

But after a little bit of research I got to thinking:

Wouldn't you be able to achieve exchanging ETH with your own token in the same contract using the "receive keyword"? Is there any problems or bad practices in having this in the same contract? or should I aim for having this in separate contracts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you should keep the token contract simple. Only include stuff that directly influences the token and can't be written separately. Stuff like: standard functionality, minting, taxes, pausability, ...

If you want to create some sort of marketplace contract for the token, do it separately. That would be a contract which accepts Eth and gives out your token.

You should keep these issue separated because of security concerns. Contracts should always be as simple as possible. Also, if you later find a bug in your marketplace contract, the token contract is still valid and not affected directly.